# drag and drop objects

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How to implement Drag and Drop multiple objects in the form in Visual Basic. The drag-able object will be provided within the same form but in a different panel.  I must be able to delete the object also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post can help you?

[Drag & Drop sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286685/drag-data-from-dg-and-other-controls-to-another-dg-in-vb-net/9293458#9293458)

It's for Grid control but you can apply to other scenarios.