# Drag and drop rows between two datatable using msflexgrid

Tags: datatable, drag, msflexgrid

I have two forms with msflexgrid to display data with datasource from datatable.

I want to drag and drop rows between two form each other. I saw this topic and edited but it doesn't work.

[Drag data from DG and other controls to another DG in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286685/drag-data-from-dg-and-other-controls-to-another-dg-in-vb-net)

This error:

[image: error]

Please help me!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post some code to show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is my form1
[form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZsfl.png)
Code form 1:

```
Imports C1.Win.C1FlexGrid
```

Public Class frm1
    Private mdt As New DataTable("Test")
    Private downHitInfo As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.HitTestInfo = Nothing

```
Private Sub frm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mdt.Columns.Add("EmplCode")
    mdt.Columns.Add("EmplName")
    mdt.Rows.Add("012345", "A")
    mdt.Rows.Add("012346", "B")
    mdt.Rows.Add("012347", "C")
    flg1.DataSource = mdt
    With flg1
        .DragMode = DragModeEnum.Manual
        .DropMode = DropModeEnum.Manual
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub flg1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles flg1.MouseDown
    Dim view As C1FlexGrid = CType(sender, C1FlexGrid)
    Dim hitInfo As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.HitTestInfo = view.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    If Not Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.None Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        downHitInfo = hitInfo
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub flg1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles flg1.MouseMove
    Dim view As C1FlexGrid = CType(sender, C1FlexGrid)
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left And Not downHitInfo Is Nothing Then
        Dim dragSize As Size = SystemInformation.DragSize
        Dim DragRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(Convert.ToInt32(downHitInfo.X - dragSize.Width / 2), _
      Convert.ToInt32(downHitInfo.Y - dragSize.Height / 2)), dragSize)
        If Not DragRect.Contains(New Point(e.X, e.Y)) Then
            'Extract the DataRow
            Dim gridRowView As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Row = DirectCast(view.Rows(downHitInfo.Row), C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Row)
            'Dim rowView As DataRowView = DirectCast(gridRowView.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
            Dim rowView As DataRowView = DirectCast(gridRowView.DataMap, DataRowView)
            'Raise the DragDrop with the extracted DataRow
            view.DoDragDrop(rowView.Row, DragDropEffects.Move)
            downHitInfo = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Dim lfrm As New frm2()
    lfrm.Show()
End Sub
```

End Class

This is form 2:
[Form 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhmEW.png)
Code of form 2:

```
Imports C1.Win.C1FlexGrid
```

Public Class frm2
    Private Sub frm2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With flg2
            .DragMode = DragModeEnum.Manual
            .DropMode = DropModeEnum.Manual
        End With
    End Sub

```
Private Sub flg2_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles flg2.DragOver
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
End Sub

Private Sub flg2_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles flg2.DragDrop
    Dim draggedRow As DataRow = CType(e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataRow)), DataRow)
End Sub
```

End Class